# No module named comments, I installed, set everything right

Tags: django

I tried pip install django-contrib-comments,pip install django-comments-xtd but still doesn't work

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'suit',
    'django.contrib.comments',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'main',
    'accounts',

    #3rd party apps
    'django_forms_bootstrap',
    'guardian',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'userena',
    'django_comments_xtd',

)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'rclone.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join (BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'rclone.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

SUIT_CONFIG = {
    'ADMIN_NAME': 'Hello'

}


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'userena.backends.UserenaAuthenticationBackend',
    'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

ANONYMOUS_USER_ID = -1  

AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'accounts.MyProfile'  


USERENA_SIGNIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/%(username)s/'
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/signin/'
LOGOUT_URL = '/accounts/signout/'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = zzzz
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = zzzzz

SITE_ID = 1

COMMENTS_APP = "django_comments_xtd"
COMMENTS_XTD_CONFIRM_EMAIL = True
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong, I followed the instructions as the doc says. I copied frameworks, when I'm about to put python manage.py syncdb no module named comments show up.

Comment: I found this, https://bitbucket.org/chris1610/satchmo/issues/537/djangocontribcommentsurlscomments-no can't understand :<

Comment: Did you `python manage.py makemigrations` before you `python manage.py migrate` ?

Comment: yes but it still shows same error

Answer (score 0):

Theres a lot more setup besides that. If you can run the server than the package is loading. You need to add the URLs and templates for it to function. You can read more at https://pythonhosted.org/django-comments-xtd/tutorial.html.

Answer (score 0):

`django.contrib.comments` was removed from Django core, so this module no longer exists. You need to remove it from `INSTALLED_APPS` as well.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'suit',
    'django.contrib.comments',  # remove this
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `'django_comments'` also in your installed apps. Both are required with `'django_comments_xtd'`. Hope it helps